# MariaDB 10.3.18 : How to get 2 records with random and distinct value?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

There is a MySQL table named stat:

```
line_name  device_name count
1001    3548001  2
1002    3548002  3
1003    3548003  6
2001    3548004  7
2002    3548005  3
2003    3548006  4
3001    3548007  3
3002    3548008  9
3003    3548009  7
```

I need to select 2 records where the first char in `line_name` is different
For example:

```
1001    3548001  2
3003    3548009  7
```

or:

```
2002    3548005  3
3001    3548007  3
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(line_name,1,LENGTH(line_name)-3)) as pack_id, device_name, count 
from stat
order by rand()
limit 2;
```

but from time to time I get the same `pack_id` in the result set

Comment: Also, it's obvious that this query could not return that result!

Comment: Strawberry, yes You right. I edited my question

Comment: Distinct is not a function, it applies to the entire row.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  One thing I want to know is whether `line_name` is 'unique'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MariaDB 10.3 you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND())` to generate a random row number for each distinct `line_name` and then select a random pair of values that have row number = 1:

```
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(line_name, 1) ORDER BY RAND()) AS rn
 FROM stat)
SELECT `line_name`, `device_name`, `count`
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=faa36de91334c81f678bde586f6903af)

Output (for a couple of runs)

```
line_name   device_name count
1003        3548003     6
3002        3548008     9

line_name   device_name count
2001        3548004     7
1003        3548003     6
```

Comment: (I don't think the trailing `LIMIT 2` is necessary.)

Comment: @RickJames given that `LEFT(line_name, 1)` could take values (based on the same data) of 1, 2 or 3, there will be 3 rows in the `CTE` which have `rn = 1`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f34f634e3036641dd1e0c87d15da9e68

Comment: Cute, but don't expect performance.  For that mere 9-row table,   38  Handler_read_rnd
   34  Handler_read_rnd_next
     21  Handler_tmp_write
       9  Handler_update
     10  Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests
    9  Innodb_rows_read

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0, you can self-join the table in a CTE to find a random pair of records that satisfy the condition, and then use `UNION ALL` to unpivot the results:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        t1.line_name line_name1,
        t1.device_name device_name1,
        t1.count count1,
        t2.line_name line_name2,
        t2.device_name device_name2,
        t2.count count2
    FROM stat t1
    INNER JOIN stat t2 ON LEFT(t1.line_name, 1) != LEFT(t2.line_name, 1)
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
)
SELECT line_name1, device_name1, count1 FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT line_name2, device_name2, count2 FROM cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c6vWPAXt26kbPNn2weJ1xG/1)**:

Run #1:

```
| line_name1 | device_name1 | count1 |
| ---------- | ------------ | ------ |
| 3001       | 3548007      | 3      |
| 2001       | 3548004      | 7      |
```

Run #2:

```
| line_name1 | device_name1 | count1 |
| ---------- | ------------ | ------ |
| 1003       | 3548003      | 6      |
| 2002       | 3548005      | 3      |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY pack_id` and select a random of the corresponding device_name or `ANY_VALUE()` if your using a MySQL >= 5.7

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(line_name, 1, 1) AS pack_id,
  line_name,
  ANY_VALUE(device_name) AS device_name,
  count
FROM stat
GROUP BY pack_id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

Older MySQL versions

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(line_name, 1, 1) AS pack_id,
  line_name,
  device_name,
  count
FROM stat
GROUP BY pack_id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d466f2/1

Note that I have also simplified the computation of pack_id

Comment: Though good approach, But this answer will limit the device_name to be only the max per line_name. However OP need it all to be random.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
select s.*
from stat s
order by row_number() over (partition by left(line_name, 1)
                            order by rand()
                           )
limit 2;
```

No subqueries are needed because window functions are allowed in `order by`.

This may not be the most efficient method.  But unless your table is large, the performance should be okay.